# Java PriorityQueue removal of arbitrary elements performance

Tags: java, performance, collections, queue

Say I have a java PriorityQueue (which java implements as a heap) that I iterate over to remove elements based on some criteria:

```
PriorityQueue q = new PriorityQueue();
...
Iterator it = q.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    if( someCriterion(it.next()) )
        it.remove();
}
```

How long does each remove() operation take? I'm not sure whether it's O(log(n)) or O(1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>If you're using the Sun implementation, it's `O(log(n))`.</strike> From the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> Implementation note: this implementation provides
>    O(log(n)) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods
>    (`offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and `add`);
>    linear time for the `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)`
>    methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods
>    (`peek`, `element`, and `size`).

Other implementations could have different complexity.

---

**Edit:** The Javadocs don't cover the performance of removing an element with an iterator, so I had to look up the source code. This is all relevant to the Sun implementation, and may differ in Apple's version, GNU Classpath, etc. Sun's source is available [here](http://download.java.net/jdk6/); it is also included in the JDK, so you might already have it installed.

In the `PriorityQueue`'s iterator, the default case for `remove()` is to call `PriorityQueue.removeAt(lastRet)`, where `lastRet` is the index that was last returned by `next()`. `removeAt()` appears to be `O(log(n))` worst case (it might have to sift the queue, but doesn't have to iterate).

However, sometimes bad things happen. From the comments of `removeAt()`:

```
/**
 * Removes the ith element from queue.
 *
 * Normally this method leaves the elements at up to i-1,
 * inclusive, untouched.  Under these circumstances, it returns
 * null.  Occasionally, in order to maintain the heap invariant,
 * it must swap a later element of the list with one earlier than
 * i.  Under these circumstances, this method returns the element
 * that was previously at the end of the list and is now at some
 * position before i. This fact is used by iterator.remove so as to
 * avoid missing traversing elements.
 */
```

When a non-null element is returned by `removeAt()`, the iterator adds it to a special queue for later use: when the iterator runs out of elements in the queue, it then iterates through this special queue. When `remove()` is called during this second phase of iteration, the iterator calls `PriorityQueue.removeEq(lastRetElt)`, where `lastRetElt` is the last element returned from the special queue. `removeEq` is forced to use a linear search to find the correct element to remove, which makes it `O(n)`. BUT it can check elements using `==` rather than `.equals()`, so its constant factor is lower than `PriorityQueue.remove(Object)`.

So, in other words, removing with an iterator is technically `O(n)`, but in practice it should be quite a bit faster than `remove(Object)`.

Comment: It doesn't specify the remove() operation time from an iterator. Removing the head will definitely take O(log(n)), but what about removing other elements?

Comment: Good question. Let me look at the source; it might use `remove(Object)`, which would make it linear.

Comment: remove() uses indexOf(), so it is linear

Comment: Doesn't this make PriorityQueue redundant, if it doesn't perform insertions and deletions in O(logn) time?